# Joining attributes from two features classes (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, feature-class, data-management

I have two feature classes containing building footprint polygons. Both are of the same area and can be superimposed (not 100% but very close). However, they do not have the same attributes. Therefore I would like to merge the attribute tables so I have the full set of attributes in one feature class.

But there's no common identification field between the two classes, so how can I link each polygon in the first class to its matching polygon in the second and merge their attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one way. I would try
[Spatial Join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) with match option

> HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN —The features in the join features will be
> matched if a target feature's center falls within them. The center of
> the feature is calculated as follows: for polygon and multipoint the
> geometry's centroid is used, and for line input the geometry's
> midpoint is used

To join the attributes from one building dataset to the other.

You will have to choose which of the two datasets geometries you want to keep.